# Django ManytoManyField add function not working

Tags: django

I'm trying to add objects into a Django ManytoManyField as I create them. But for some reason after I call the add function when I try to print whats in that field I get none. This is the code where I am attempting to add objects into the field.

```
new_recommendation = Recommendation.objects.create(recommender=sender,
                                                   recomendee=reciever,
                                                   relationship=relationship,
                                                   recomendee_position=position)



new_recommendation.save()
for id in event_final_id:
    event = Event.objects.get(id=id)
    event.save()
    new_recommendation.recomendee_events.add(event)
    new_recommendation.save()
```

This is the code for the class I am using.

```
class Recommendation(models.Model):
     recommender = models.ForeignKey(StartupMember, 
            related_name='recommender')
     recomendee = models.ForeignKey(StartupMember, 
           related_name='recommendee')
     recommendation_text = models.TextField(max_length=500, 
          default='')
     relationship = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     recomendee_position = models.ForeignKey(Experience, 
           default=None)
     recomendee_events = models.ManyToManyField(Event, default=None)
     recomendee_ventures_projects = models.ManyToManyField(Startup, 
         default=None)
```

Comment: Where are you printing the values? Also, what's the point of saving the Event you just got?

Comment: I was just experimenting with the save function. I print the values right after the last line in the for loop

Comment: There's not enough code here to fully debug.  Specifically, we don't know that there is anything in `event_final_id` or if there is a bug in how you are printing the values.